Why Customer Service Experience Cloud doesn't have Compact Header component?
Why Customer Service Experience Cloud doesn't have Compact Header component?
Customer required to adjust Header height but this is not possible since Customer Service community template doesn't have  Compact Header component.
Are there any workaround for this purpose?

did you find any solution for this.

I don't remember, I am no longer involved in that project anymore
